# Compare two timestamp columns and if difference is greater than 1 hour, trigger email alert(bash)

Tags: shell, awk, timestamp, text-processing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
user1,135.4,MATLAB,server1,14:53:59,15:54:28
user2,3432,Solver_HF+,server1,14:52:01,14:54:28
user3,3432,Solver_HF+,server1,14:52:01,15:54:14
user4,3432,Solver_HF+,server1,14:52:01,14:54:36
```

I want to run a comparison between the last two columns and if the difference is greater than an hour(such as lines 1 and 3) it will trigger something like this:

```
echo "individual line from file" | mail -s "subject" email@site.com
```

I was trying to come up with a possible solution using awk, but I'm still fairly new to linux and couldn't quite figure out something that worked.

Comment: why not have the process that creates that data calculate the time diff. but display it lke `hh.mm` Very easy in a database. Then you can just check for a number greater than `0.99`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

the following awk scripts maybe is your want

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
    {a="2019 01 01 " gensub(":"," ","g",$5);
    b="2019 01 01 " gensub(":"," ","g",$6);
    c = int((mktime(b)-mktime(a))/60)}
    {if (c >= 60){system("echo "individual line from file" | mail -s "subject" email@site.com")}}' your_filename
```

then put the scritps into `crontab` or other trigger
for example

```sh
*/5 * * * *  awk_scripts.sh
```

if you just want check new line .  use `tail -n filename` may be more useful than `cat`

Comment: You should never cat the file to  `awk`, always `awk 'code' file` Also the backslash is not needed, only when splitting line in middle of code.block.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: (using gnu awk due to mktime)

```
awk -F, '{
    split($(NF-1),t1,":");
    split($NF,t2,":");
    d1=mktime("0 0 0 "t1[1]" "t1[2]" "t1[3]" 0");
    d2=mktime("0 0 0 "t2[1]" "t2[2]" "t2[3]" 0");
    if (d2-d1>3600) print $0}' file
user1,135.4,MATLAB,server1,14:53:59,15:54:28
user3,3432,Solver_HF+,server1,14:52:01,15:54:14
```

- Using field separator as comma to get the second last and last field.
- The split the two field inn to array `t1` and `t2` to get hour min sec
- mktime converts this to seconds.
- do the math and print only lines with more than `3600` seconds
- This can then be piped to other commands.

See how time function are used int gnu awk:  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Comment: So I pipe in this command at the end:
 "| mail -s "a subject" email@site.com"
But it still triggers an email even if their is not return from the awk command. Possible work around?

Comment: @colm That I can not help you with.  But what we do to analyze log and get alert is using Splunk.  Its free to use for 500MB/day. (with some functional removed.